# Why are no parameters better than few parameter methods?

Tags: unit-testing, clean-code, methods, parameters

In Clean Code, Robert C. Martin states that no parameter methods are better than those with very few parameters. I'm kind of confused as no parameter methods are usually harder to unit test and tend to be more coupled.

I think his rational is that since a class should only fulfill one very specific task the coupling is alright but what about unit testing?

Also the approach towards atomic methods would favor reuse of the methods so why would you try to couple them to instance methods preferably?

Comment: Can you give an example of how, in your experience, methods with no parameters tend to be more coupled and harder to unit test.

Comment: author explains in details why they think this way about testability, is there anything unclear in their reasoning? "Imagine the difficulty of
writing all the test cases to ensure that all the various combinations of arguments work
properly. If there are no arguments, this is trivial. If there’s one argument, it’s not too hard.
With two arguments the problem gets a bit more challenging. With more than two arguments,
testing every combination of appropriate values can be daunting..."

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, a method with no parameters either does nothing, or it is impure, eg it is coupled to some state and so is clearly more coupled. However, it doesn't necessarily follow that such methods are harder to test, they just require more ceremony in setting up that state prior to calling the method.

Comment: @gnat, that is a non-sequitor argument on the part of the author. If those variables aren't passed via parameters, they must be set up in some other way. Either way, there are as many combinations that need testing.

Comment: @DavidArno I re-checked the book and it doesn't look non-sequitur. Further in the discussed paragraph author makes it totally clear that they  accept cases when parameters are indeed necessary. My understanding of the reasoning I quoted is one needs to avoid introducing parameters when these aren't really needed (example that immediately springs to mind is when instance variable can/should be used instead of parameter)

Comment: If the function has no parameters and doesn't access global variables (*shudder*), it might as well be a constant.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: He isn't talking about functions, he is talking about methods. Methods always have one implicit argument.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, apart from when they don't, eg static methods...

Comment: @DavidArno: Static methods aren't methods, they are namespaced procedures with a confusing name.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, Nope. If language X chooses to call particular subroutines, methods, then they are methods in that language. If language Y chooses to call the same thing functions, then they are functions. Trying to impose your opinion on when languages are allowed to call certain subroutines, methods, and when they should call them functions, is both daft and arrogant.

Comment: @DavidArno: What a language calls or doesn't call something is irrelevant. This question is about interpreting a statement by Uncle Bob, and thus the only thing that matters is how Uncle Bob defines the term. Which, as far as I can remember, is how Smalltalk, Self, Newspeak, Ruby, Java (note that Java specifically distinguishes between "methods" and "static methods" and Uncle Bob only talks about "methods", not "static methods"), Python, Fancy, C♯, etc. also define it.

Comment: @FrankHileman - Your total lack of historical knowledge is clearly demonstrated in your comment. Sure, "Uncle Bob" hasn't been as influential in changing things lately as in the past, but in his prime he was truly one of the icons of the programming world. He was one of the first to actually attempt to use substantive reasoning for determining why one design/implementation is better than another. Before him, one version of code was deemed better than another simply because 'the person in charge said they like it better'. No reason, they just like it better....

Comment: ...Much of what "Uncle Bob" made popular is quoted on this site quite frequently and most people don't even know it was popularized by him. I liken "Uncle Bob" to Eddie Van Halen. Eddie hasn't had a big impact lately but you can hear his style in a huge number of guitarists of today. "Uncle Bob" has had a big influence on a huge number of programmers of today, including many who don't even know they've been indirectly influenced by him.

Comment: " However, it doesn't necessarily follow that such methods are harder to test, they just require more ceremony in setting up that state prior to calling the method. "   Isn't "requires more ceremony" the same as "harder"?

Comment: @gnat I think what DavidArno means is that no matter if they are parameters or instance variables, the combinatorial complexity of all data to be tested doesn't change. If Uncle Bob meant *"Zero-parameter methods [with data stored in object state instead] make the behavior more testable than multiple-parameter methods"*, I do see the non sequitur.

Comment: @NickKeighley You're technically correct (the best kind).

Comment: @guillaume31 yeah I was also thinking about this but... no, I don't think this reasoning is valid. When you use instance variable instead of method parameter this leads to different design and testing approaches. Even the range of the instance variable can be subject to class invariants, as opposed to method parameter

Comment: @gnat I think you might be overinterpreting what Uncle Bob wrote. *" [...] writing all the test cases to ensure that all the various combinations of arguments work properly. If there are no arguments, this is trivial. If there’s one argument, it’s not too hard."* and so on, clearly indicates that the important bit is the combination of different valid inputs, and that variation in the number of parameters results in orders of magnitude more complex tests. Not just tests where input validation would have to be duplicated, as opposed to ones benefiting from centralized class invariants.

Comment: @Dunk Glad to know you know me so well. "Uncle Bob" has only had a negative influence in the industry. One only has to read various "Clean Code" questions to understand this.

Comment: @FrankHileman - "Uncle Bob" lost me once he started writing about that craftsmanship stuff, which was the beginnings of "Clean Code". But that doesn't discredit his vast positive influences from before he catapulted off on that tangent. I have a completely opposite perspective from the craftsmanship view which is why I stopped paying attention. Computers are very systematic and predictable and I believe software development needs to be the same way, not some black magic art. IMO, the craftsmanship view only gives developers an excuse to not be systematic.

Comment: @Dunk I agree, some of his earlier work was much better than the later things. However if you review the Clean Code questions, the name of which ("clean code") completely corrupts any discussion of truly clean code, you can see it has caused many problems and lots of ravioli code.

Comment: @Dunk My main point was that this forum should be about software engineering, not the dubious opinions of one author regarding low level details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding of Uncle Bobs claim is: *think carefully about the life cycle of your objects.*

I for my self found that quite often I can turn some of the method parameters into constructor parameters since they do not change during the use of the object.

In contrast to Uncle Bobs I don't find *no parameter* methods superior. That is because my methods often create a *return value* that is used in the next method. Adding that return value to the objects state instead of passing it as parameter to the next method decreases readability because it hides a dependency between those methods. This also becomes a problem when you apply your IDEs *automated refactoring* `move method` which makes the (temporary) member variable accessible for the object the method moved to...

Also it opens the possibility to change the order of method in a wrong way. The "no state" version would throw a compiler error in such case...

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to pass only parameters used specifically in that method.  Object members should have an impact across almost all public methods.  It would be silly to force yourself to pass no parameters to methods just as it would be silly to force yourself to pass all parameters in every single call.

Comment: I think OP is misunderstanding the book. He never recommends passing return values as state inside the calling object instead of explicit return, he recommends combining cohesive state so that you end up with a single object and not 3 different variables.  Its literally just applying SOLID principles, not anything more than that.  Uncle Bob isn't claiming that all no parameter methods are better, but a cohesive class with no parameter methods is better than a class with methods that contain parameters that might as well be class members.

Answer (score 7):

The advice of Uncle Bob should be taken with a large grain of salt. It is always important to understand the context for advice and the trade-offs involved.

Bob is a proponent of the object-oriented paradigm. The underlying premise is you want to follow the OO paradigm. If you prefer a functional style or some pragmatic middle ground, his advice might not be for you.

If I understand you correctly you prefer to test methods individually. This is much simpler if there is less reliance on object state, and more on parameters. Pure side-effect free functions are especially easy to test. But this is functional style. In OO style, the "unit" is the object, not the method. You don't test a single method in isolation, you always test the behavior of an object.

When you say methods with fewer parameters are more coupled, I assume you mean more coupled to the state of the object and other methods on the same object? This is not necessarily a bad thing in OO - rather you try to achieve low coupling *between* objects and high cohesion for the object.

I don't think anybody have proven one paradigm to be superior to another, so this all comes down to opinion (or religion). But *if* you accept the premise that you want to strive for a pure OO architecture, then the advice of Bob makes sense.

Comment: "Uncle Bob" is a proponent of his own ideas, more than object oriented programming in general.

Answer (score 3):

In Uncle Bob's coding style, there are many small methods with descriptive names that take no parameter but are just there to structure the code for the reader. You will usually not unit-test these methods directly, but through higher-level methods of a class. Do not make the mistake to think that you have to have a corresponding test method for each method in the class under test.

Secondly, as correctly stated in the comments, **methods** with no parameters still know all about the internal state of the class, they have the impleicit **this** parameter. Testing a method's behavior thus depends on the parameters **and** the state of the surrounding object. If you have no parameters, that is actually less state to think about when testing a method. I you call a method from a test, you configure it by changing the object's state. Were there parameters, this would be an even larger state space for your tests to cover, so technically you could say having zero arguments is the best case.

That said, in the end it still depends on your actual code whether it is easy to test. Say you have a function `f(int a)` with one parameter. You could always make `int a` a field of the class and the function `f()` now has zero parameters. This would not make it easier or harder to test.